# Django - legacy db and problems with 'id' field

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I'm integrating a MySQL database from a php app into a new Django project. [Inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) worked well, I just had to change a couple of fields to ForeignKeys and now all the reading and editing current data is working great.

The problem is when I try to create a new entry, I get the error **`"Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"`**. The traceback starts from the `form.save()` call and the exception is coming from the MySQL cursor. In most cases the column is named `id` but in one case it is a named value:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model): #normal "id" named pk 
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id', default=None)
    other_fields = ...

class ModelTwo(models.Model): #specific pk
    named_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='named_pk',
                                default=None)
    other_fields = ...
```

For ModelTwo, when I POST a valid form, I get the error, but then if I go back to my data list, the new item shows up! And after I checked the latest `id` values in the shell, I can see that they are incrementing correctly.

But for ModelOne (with just `id`), the error still shows up, and the pk become 2147483647 (the max) and subsequent saves fail because of duplicate ids. (the next highest pk is only 62158)

What do I need to do to get these id fields working correctly?

---

update: Still no luck fixing this. Thinking about dumping the data and importing it into fresh, Django-built tables. Still looking for a solution to this problem.

---

update2:
Info from db shell

ModelOne:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------+------+---------+-----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null  | Key  | Default | Extra           |
| id          | int(11)      | NO    | PRI  | NULL    | auto_increment  |
```

ModelTwo:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------+------+---------+-----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null  | Key  | Default | Extra           |
| named_pk    | int(11)      | NO    | PRI  | NULL    | auto_increment  |
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `default=None`?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman - same exact thing. I only added it in an attempt to directly address what it seemed like the error was pointing at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up exporting the data from the original database, and loading it into a fresh db which was generated by my models/project.

I think I had tried too many things with the copy of the original database I was working on and botched up the underlying SQL for the pk field.

I'm just glad that I was only working with a copy.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, same fix. The data export, then recreation of the tables allowed django to set up the mysql auto-increment attribute properly delegating generation of the new pk to mysql.

Answer (score 5):

I met the same issue after some complex South migration.
We wanted to avoid to reload the database (dump/import), luckily it will help other peoples who fall on this post after searching for the same issue.

We found a solution which solve this problem without the need of exporting and importing the database.

For a table named auth_user, the following MySQL command will fixe the above error message:

```
ALTER TABLE auth_user MODIFY `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

original solution from :

http://webit.ca/2012/01/field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value/

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense to define pk for ModelTwo (as your are already doing) because your pk has different name 'named_pk'. However, no need to explicitly define 'id' as your pk for ModelOne. Django will create id column by default. So do not define the id column at all for ModelOne.

**UPDATE:** remove "default=None" from the model and default NULL from the database for ModelTwo for named_pk

Comment: I've tried this approach too. If I go into the SQL and look at the able structure there already is an 'id' column set to auto_increment. I think the problem lies in Django recognizing it. Any ideas why the error is coming up for ModelTwo despite it actually saving data correctly?

Comment: I updated my question to show the MySQL output from `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name`. I don't quite follow what you are saying, ModelTwo has no column named 'id'. The field 'named_pk' has always been the PK column. For that model, the actual value of 'named_pk' is very important (it correlates to sequential order numbers in a purchasing system).

Comment: If there is no 'id' column in ModelTwo table, then whats the error when saving ModelTwo?

Comment: "Field 'named_pk' doesn't have a default value" -- But as I mentioned earlier, despite the error for ModelTwo, it saves properly with the right increment of "named_pk". I just have to leave the error page and go back to my list to see it.

Comment: remove "default=None" from the model and default NULL from the database for ModelTwo for named_pk

Comment: I can't seem to find the MySQL command to remove the default altogether. I tried `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER id DROP DEFAULT;` but it's not making a difference, still showing as default null when I use the `SHOW COLUMNS` command.